# Conditional validation with XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

This is probably basic but I am struggling to implement it with my basic knowledge of XML and XML Schema.

Any help is gratefully received.

Given the following XML file snippet:

```
<record>
   ...
   <update_type>3</update_type>
   <reason>User entered in error</reason>
   ...
</record>
<record>
   ...
   <update_type>1</update_type>
   <reason></reason>
   ...
</record>
```

Is there a way I can conditionally validate the XML file ensuring the `<reason>` string element is mandatory when the `<update_type>` numeric element has a value of 3 but optional when the `<update_type>` is another value?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No you can't**, not with XML Schema.

You need to write that logic in your code, after you validate the XML structure with the Schema and make sure it's content is valid.

Comment: I had pretty much got to that conclusion but was hoping I was wrong.